# Authentication with old password no longer supported

Tags: mysql

I get an exception, and I can not get any found answers to work.

The exception is this:
**Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords**

when logging on to my mysql database from my .Net project

At my machine it works (as usual) but on my server it doesn't.

On my machine I run  `5.5.40 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

On my server they run `5.1.56-community`

I use these packages in my MVC site:

```
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.9.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MySql.Web" version="6.9.6" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I use this way to connect:

```
 const string ConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=mydatabase;" + "UID=myusername;" + "PASSWORD=mypassword;";
```

Any idea on what to do?

I see this answer all the time:

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0;
SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('YOURDATABASEPASSWORD');
```

But it doesn't work because the setting 'old passwords' on the server is never changed.

the server setting for 'old passwords' is 'ON', the local one is 'OFF'

Comment: The old_password is a session setting. Do you stay within the same session? Also should it not be Pwd=yourpassword in the connect string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar issue a few days back after an upgrade to Mysql 5.6 from 5.5 even though the user was using the new 42-bit hash for awhile and not the old 16-bit hash.

I tend to stay away from the set command when updating a password instead use: `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='yourusername';`
then do a `flush privileges;`

If that does not work. Delete the user, do a flush privileges, recreate that user, issue proper grants, and do another flush privileges.

This is what worked in our situation for the Authentication with old password not supported error.

Comment: unfortunately no luck with this: `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='yourusername';`; I don't have rights to do that....

Comment: Ah, ok, I definately don't have these rights. Thanks for the help though, appreciate it. Can't find any good info about it...

Comment: It's shared hosting, somewhere via email, I've just sent him/her an email, hope I get a reply.

Comment: I've marked this one as answer, even though my personal situation is not fixed. I asked my provider if they could help but all they say is that I can do  it myself in my plesk environment, which doesn't work. So that's my payback for choosing one of the cheaper providers ;-)